# Get ServletContext in Application

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

Could you possibly explain how I can get the `ServletContext` instance in my `Application`'s sub-class? Is it possible? I have tried to do it like in the following snippet but it does not seem to work - the `ctx` is not set:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

//...

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MainApplication extends Application {

    @Context ServletContext ctx;

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {     
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
//...
        return classes;
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app ...>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>environment</param-name>
  <param-value>development</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <filter>
  <filter-name>jersey-filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
   <init-param>
   <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
   <param-value>my.MainApplication</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
...
</web-app>
```

The problem is that I need to get context parameters from it. If there is another way, I would be grateful if somebody gave a hint.

---

I understand that `Context` annotation might not be purposed for this. Actually, I do not need `ServletContext` itself. If only I could get context params from web.xml, I would be absolutely happy.

Here is an example of what I really need:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;

public class MainApplication extends Application {

    @Context ServletContext ctx;

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        Set<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>();
        final String environment = ctx.getInitParameter("environment");
        //final String environment = ... get context parameter from web xml
        set.add(new AbstractBinder() {

            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(new BaseDataAccess(environment)).to(DataAccess.class);             
            }
        });
        //...
        return set;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Industrious Which application server you are using?

Comment: @Paul Vargas I am using Tomcat 7

Comment: @Buhb, this is not a duplicate. He's trying to access `ServletContext` from the `Application` whereas the other post is trying to access it from a `Resource`.

Comment: @Gili Very true. I've removed the comment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since Jersey 2.5, ServletContext can be injected directly in constructor:
https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2184

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication(@Context ServletContext servletContext) {
       // TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: this will also work as a parameter on specific methods. Also, the java.net link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

`@Context` can be made available on `ResoureConfig` by injecting it as a constructor parameter using `@Context`. **Another way to access it is through an event handler**.

Try the below code.

```
@ApplicationPath("...")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        register(StartupHandler.class);
    }

    private static class StartupHandler extends  AbstractContainerLifecycleListener {
        @Context
        ServletContext ctx;

        @Override
        public void onStartup(Container container) {
            // You can put code here for initialization. 
        }
    }
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Injection happens when you enter service method. Check if this is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is interesting statement in documentation for Jersey version 1.18 for class
[com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.18/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer.html)

> The servlet or filter may be configured to have an initialization
>   parameter "com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass" or
>   "javax.ws.rs.Application" and whose value is a fully qualified name of
>   a class that implements ResourceConfig or Application. If the concrete
>   class has a constructor that takes a single parameter of the type Map
>   then the class is instantiated with that constructor and an instance
>   of Map that contains all the initialization parameters is passed as
>   the parameter.

If my understanding is correct the following constructor must be invoced with "an instance of Map that contains all the initialization parameters"

```
public class ExampleApplication extends Application {
    public ExampleApplication(Map initParams) {
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is appropriate part of web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
       <param-value>experiment.service.ExampleApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

But somehow it failed for me with the following message:

> SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public
>   experiment.service.ExampleApplication(java.util.Map) at parameter
>   index 0

And for current version of Jersey (2.5.1) there are no such statement in documentstion:
https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ApplicationEventListener` interface to get the `ServletContext`. After initialization has finished, you can 'catch' an `ApplicationEvent` and use the injected `ServletContext` to work with.

Works fine with: *org.glassfish.jersey : 2.12*
For additional versions, pls use comments - i dont know, sry.

[Jersey Docs - 20.1.2. Event Listeners](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html#d0e14121)

Your `MainApplication`:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MainApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {     
        Set<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        set.add(MainApplicationListener.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

... or alternative `MainResourceConfig` (I prefer to use this one):

```
public class MainResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public MainResourceConfig() {
        register(MainApplicationListener.class);
    }
}
```

And the `ApplicationEventListener`:

```
public class MainApplicationListener implements ApplicationEventListener {

    @Context
    private ServletContext ctx; //not null anymore :)

    @Override
    public void onEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        switch (event.getType()) {
            case INITIALIZATION_FINISHED:
            // do whatever you want with your ServletContext ctx
            break;
    }

    @Override
    public RequestEventListener onRequest(RequestEvent requestEvent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `@Context` in your `Application` but in a Resource class.

```
@Path("/foos")
public class FooResource {

  @Context
  ServletContext ctx;

  @GET
  public Response getFoos() {
    return Response.ok().build();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However I am not asking where to use @Context, I am asking about how to get the `SerlvetContext`. I have updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: @Industrious in your case, `BaseDataAccess` can use `@Context ServletContext ctx.`