# Jersey 2: How to pass parameters from web.xml to Application?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

My web container knows whether my application is running in debug or release mode. I'd like to pass this information to my ResourceConfig/Application class, but it's not clear how to read this information back out.

Is it possible to pass information by way of servlet/filter parameters? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed in Jersey 2.5: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2184

You should now be able to inject `@Context ServletContext` into the `Application` constructor.

Here is an example of how this is expected to work:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
  private final String myInitParameter;

  public MyApplication(@Context ServletContext servletContext)
  {
    this.myInitParameter = servletContext.getInitParameter("myInitParameter");
  }
}
```

You can also invoke `ServiceLocator.getService(ServletContext.class)` to get the `ServletContext` from any point in the application.

Comment: Good to know! Could you provide an example in order to actually answer the question posed?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'm doing it:

in `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>
  <description>When set to true, all operations include debugging info</description>
  <param-name>com.example.DEBUG_API_ENABLED</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and in my `Application` subclass:

```java
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
  @Context
  protected ServletContext sc;

  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    boolean debugging = Boolean.parseBoolean(sc
            .getInitParameter("com.example.DEBUG_API_ENABLED"));

    if (debugging) {
        // enable debugging resources
```

Comment: I unaccepted this answer, as I'm getting a ServletContext value of null. Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/q/19450202/14731 I'm not the only one.

Comment: You may want to be more specific in your question then. My code is working for me, is Java EE spec compliant and does what you asked in your question. I noticed you gave more details in a post to the Jersey mailing list that you don't mention here: you want the property to become available in the constructor?Why not accept my answer for the question you posted here and ask a new question with all the details upfront?

Comment: If you definitely want the parameters in the Application constructor, I think you'll need to look at one of the various other suggestions (passing them as system properties to the JVM, use of a property file, etc.). But if you just need those parameters at application start-up time (as opposed to per request for instance), a @Provider class (where injection is supported in constructors) may help. In GlassFish 3.1.2.2 with Jersey 1.11.1 where I tried, these are instantiated straight after the instantiation of your Application subclass (where I return my `@Provider` class from `getSingletons`).

Answer (score 0):

In Jersey 1 it was possible to pass `@Context ServletContext servletContext` to the constructor of an `Application` class, but in Jersey 2 this no longer works. It seems Jersey 2 will only inject at request time.

To work around this in Jersey 2, use an anonymous `ContainerRequestFilter` to gain access to a ServletContext at request time and pass the required init parameters into the `Application` class.

```java
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Context protected ServletContext servletContext;
  private String myInitParameter;

  @Override
  public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    singletons.add(new ContainerRequestFilter() {
      @Override
      public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
        synchronized(MyApplication.this) {
          if(myInitParameter == null) {
            myInitParameter = servletContext.getInitParameter("myInitParameter");
            // do any initialisation based on init params here
          }
        }
      }
      return singletons;
    });
  };
}
```